# Amazon lex error-An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am developing a chatbot using lex.I created one intent called "latestdetails" and one slot "uniquename".I want to validate the slot "uniquename" such that it does not accept alphabets and ask the message "please enter again" when the input is wrong . Below is my code in python.

When testing the lambda function,I get the correct response but when lambda function is connected with lex via initialization and validation code hook,I get the following error at bot :"Amazon lex  error-An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled".

I saw related questions in stackoverflow but I am not able to get the required solution.

```
import os
import time
import json
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def get_slots(event):
    return event['currentIntent']['slots']
    
def elicit_slot(intent_name, slots, slot_to_elicit ,message):
    
    response =  {
    "dialogAction":
    {
        "type":"ElicitSlot",
        "intentName": intent_name,
        "slots": slots,
        "slotToElicit": slot_to_elicit,
         "message": {
            "content": message,
            "contentType": "PlainText"
                    }
        
        
    }
                    
                }
    return response      
def delegate(slots):

    response =  {
    "dialogAction":
    {
        "type":"Delegate",
        "slots": slots
        
    }
                    
                }
    return response
def close():
    response =  {
    "dialogAction":
    {
        "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
        "type":"Close",
        "message":
            {
                "contentType":"PlainText",
                "content": "Hey your ticket has been raised"
            }
    }
                    
                }
                
    return response

def dispatch(event):
    intent_name=event['currentIntent']['name']
    if intent_name == 'latestdetails':            
        source = event['invocationSource']                        
        if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
    
                    slots= get_slots(event)
                    uniquename = event["currentIntent"]["slots"]["uniquename"]                                                                      
                    if  uniquename.isalpha():
                        
                        return elicit_slot(intent_name,'uniquename','uniquename','please enteragain')
                                    
                    return delegate(slots)
                    return close('Fulfilled')
        elif source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':               
                    return close()



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return dispatch(event)
```